# WPF Custom Button Control Command Not Firing

Tags: wpf, binding, controls

I created an override of a button:

```
public class LauncherButton : Button
{
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(LauncherButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    public string Caption
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(LauncherButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));



    public ICommand ExecuteCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ExecuteCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ExecuteCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExecuteCommandProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("ExecuteCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(LauncherButton));

}
```

I use it here:

```
    <controls:LauncherButton Caption="Job Phases"
                                   ImageSource="/FMG.UI.WPF.Shared;component/Media/Images/jobphase_128.png"
                                   Margin="10"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TabletLauncherButtonStyle}"
                                   ExecuteCommand="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{x:Static enums:View.JobPhases}"/>
```

and the view's VM:

```
public class TabletHomeViewModel : _HomeViewBase
{
    private ICommand _ItemSelectedCommand;
    public ICommand ItemSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ItemSelectedCommand == null)
                _ItemSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand(p => itemSelecteExecuted((View)p), p => itemSelecteCanExecute((View)p));


            return _ItemSelectedCommand;
        }
    }


    private bool itemSelecteCanExecute(View view)
    {
        return true;
    }
    private void itemSelecteExecuted(View view)
    {
    }
}
```

The ItemSelectedCommand's Getter fires on startup, but when I click on the button, the command doesn't fire. The Output Window doesn't show any binding problems.

If I wire up a click event for it, that does fire.

Anyone see what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see place where you would link click to `ExecuteCommand`. Besides each `Button` already supports `Command` which is executed when button is clicked

Comment: That did it. I removed the 'ExecuteCommand' command and bound to the native Command. Many thanks